How to remove empty dates from the x-axis? (matplotlib.pyplot)
I am trying to create a candlestick chart using some data for XAUUSD, which represents gold in the forex market.
The X-axis (time axis) has gaps due to holidays, and there are also gaps in the live market data because it's a 1-minute timeframe, and there may not have been any trades during certain intervals, especially at 00:00 but also possibly at other times.
I want to remove these gaps from the plot. How can I do this while I have to use matplotlib.pyplot?
This is my code:
def plot_data(df, candle_length):
    green_df = df[df.Close > df.Open].copy()
    green_df["Height"] = green_df["Close"] - green_df["Open"]
    red_df = df[df.Close < df.Open].copy()
    red_df["Height"] = red_df["Open"] - red_df["Close"]
    doji_df = df[df.Close == df.Open].copy()
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
    ax = fig.add_subplot()
    ax.grid(linestyle='--')
    if len(green_df) > 0:
        ax.vlines(x=green_df.index, ymin=green_df["Low"], ymax=green_df["High"], color="#00CC00")
        ax.bar(x=green_df.index, height=green_df["Height"], width=candle_length/1440, bottom=green_df["Open"], color="#00CC00")
    if len(red_df) > 0:
        ax.vlines(x=red_df.index, ymin=red_df["Low"], ymax=red_df["High"], color="#CC0000")
        ax.bar(x=red_df.index, height=red_df["Height"], width=candle_length/1440, bottom=red_df["Close"], color="#CC0000")
    if len(doji_df) > 0:
        ax.vlines(x=doji_df.index, ymin=doji_df["Low"], ymax=doji_df["High"], color="#888888")
        ax.hlines(xmin=pd.to_datetime(doji_df.Timestamp - candle_length*30, unit="s"), xmax=pd.to_datetime(doji_df.Timestamp + candle_length*30, unit="s"), y=doji_df["Open"], colors="#888888")
    fig.tight_layout()

plot_data(get_candles(symbol, timeframe, candle_count, candle_length, max_time_period), candle_length)

And the output:
image
I found this which says:
dt_all = pd.date_range(start=df['Date'].iloc[0],end=df['Date'].iloc[-1], freq = '5min')
dt_obs = [d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for d in df['Date']]
dt_breaks = [d for d in dt_all.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").tolist() if not d in dt_obs]
fig.update_xaxes(rangebreaks=[dict(dvalue = 5*60*1000, values=dt_breaks)])

It works well with plotly but does not fix my problem because there is no update_xaxes function for figures in pyplot
Is there a Pyplot equivalent for the Plotly code above or any other method to done that purpose?

See the various function related to axis ticks

If you have mplfinance available, they will accommodate market holiday hours. Please refer to my past answers and github.

dear @paime, I'm not sure if the functions you mentioned can help me because I need something that can adjust the spacing of the x-axis. for example, I have data for positions 1 and 3, but I want to display them at positions 1 and 2 with labels 1 and 3, without any space between them. Of course, one option is to show all the data with equal spacing and manually label all of them on the x-axis, but I'm hoping for a more efficient solution, similar to what can be done with plotly. If I'm mistaken about the capabilities of those functions, please provide additional guidance.

dear @r-beginners, I have to work with this dataset and pyplot, so I can't and didn't use mplfinance. If it's needed, I can put an example of the dataset that I have in the question.

Broken axis then ?

If you can't use mplfinance you may look at its implementation of the required capability.

@paime brokenaxis was designed for a different purpose, showing continuous data in two, three intervals that  are deemed representative and/or interesting, clearly showing the breaks between these intervals. The OP has nearly opposite needs.

@gboffi Yes but the idea of plotting over multiple axes tweaked to look like a single one can be reused, see proposed answer.

Here is a way by plotting over multiple contiguous axes, following the broken axis example of the matplotlib documentation, and the idea of breaks_idxs as in plotly.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Data
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
y = np.random.randn(len(x))
std = np.random.rand(len(x))

# Getting that the way you want
breaks_idxs = [5, 10]

# Splitting the data for multiple axes
xs = np.split(x, breaks_idxs)
ys = np.split(y, breaks_idxs)
stds = np.split(std, breaks_idxs)
n_splits = len(breaks_idxs) + 1

# Creating the axes without horizontal spaces between them
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=n_splits, gridspec_kw={"wspace": 0}, figsize=(10, 5))

# Can't sharey=True, or can't turn of spines individually
ymin = (y - std).min()
ymax = (y + std).max()

for i, (ax, x_, y_, std_) in enumerate(zip(axes, xs, ys, stds)):

    # Plot info
    ax.set_title(f"Week {i + 1}")
    ax.vlines(x_, y_ - std_, y_ + std_, color="C0", lw=2)
    ax.scatter(x_, y_, c="C1", marker="s")

    # Make sure axes share y range
    ax.set_ylim(ymin * 1.1, ymax * 1.1)

    # Make sure x-axis transitions are smooth
    # might introduce a computation for "0.5"
    ax.set_xlim(x_[0] - 0.5, x_[-1] + 0.5)

    # Remove spines and ticks
    sbs = ax.get_subplotspec()
    if not sbs.is_first_col():
        ax.spines.left.set_visible(False)
        ax.yaxis.set_ticks([])
    if not sbs.is_last_col():
        ax.spines.right.set_visible(False)


plt.show()


